# IE will not download any files

Tags: windows, windows-xp, internet-explorer

Error message:
`cannot download 'file' from 'wherever'.

Internet explorer was not able to open this internet site, please try again later.`

This occurs when downloading anything through IE for a single user on a PC, that was recently migrated from Vista to XP, user authenticates through a domain and has local admin rights..

- Can browse internet fine
- Different user on same PC, works fine..
- firefox, same user, works fine
- Ran antimalware, nothing picked up.
- re-installed IE
- also having problems in outlook, no html embedded images may be downloaded
- security software has been disabled, no change.
- no proxy server

I am at a loss to what could cause this right now.. please help :)

Comment: You've reset the IE security zones settings back to defaults, right?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks chuckx,
But unfortunately the issue was already resolved :3

The temp folder for IE was set to read-only, strangely enough it seemed to only matter for this one user.. removing the read only attribute immediately resolved all issues.

Doesn't make 100% sense but hell.. Microsoft.. amiright? :)

Comment: Isn't the temp folder per user?

Comment: Maybe, I didn't fix it so I am not 100% on the details :3

Answer (score 0):

This is a shot in the dark...

1. delete **Temporary Internet Files** and clear **History** via IE's **Internet Options**.
2. log in as another user
3. manually delete **Documents and Settings\problem user\Local Settings\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\index.dat**
4. restart